# When using string match, are you required to escape special characters?

Tags: escaping, tcl

I am working on a script to parse a certain fault code out of a SOAP message using tcl, and I have finally come to the part where I compare the message to the desired message. As you can see, I am trying to check if the string "9000" is contained in the array element "$soap(Fault)"

---

```
if { [ string match *\<FaultCode\>9000\</FaultCode\>* $soap(Fault) ] } {

    # -- Success case

} else {

    # -- fail case

}
```

---

In the example I have provided, I have escaped all of the "special characters" in tcl:

```
&;`'"|*?~<>^()[]{}$\
```

but is it required? Could one simply do:

```
*<FaultCode>9000</FaultCode>*  ?
```

---

I have looked around pretty thoroughly and haven't been able to find something quite as precise as what I am asking. I was going to ask in the tcl chat room, but I couldn't find one!

Thanks

Comment: There is a Tcl chat: http://www.tcl.tk/community/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that no, you don't need to escape **all** those characters. In fact, some of those characters aren't even special.

There are two layers here: first, at the tcl parsing level: reading through [tcl's parsing rules](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), you have a few options:

- Wrap your argument in double quotes. (but then you have to worry about embedded quotes,   [commands], and $variables)
- Wrap your argument in braces. (but then you have to worry about nesting braces)
- Use the bare word as you have above (but then you have to worry about leading braces, quotes, whitespace, and everything as for double quotes, above.)

All of that is just determining what gets passed to [string match] - the second layer involves how [string match] deals with this pattern (it's not a regex, by the way, it's just a [glob-style pattern](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40)). There are only these special characters in tcl's glob style patterns: *, ?, [], . If you want any of these to be treated as literals, you have to escape them. Anything else is treated as a literal match, so you don't have to worry about the <>'s, or the /.

So, this line is fine:

```
string match *<FaultCode>9000</FaultCode>* $soap(Fault)
```

But you could also use these styles to set off the match pattern, stylistically.

```
string match "*<FaultCode>9000</FaultCode>*" $soap(Fault)
string match {*<FaultCode>9000</FaultCode>*} $soap(Fault)
```

Answer (score 2):

For `string match` the only special characters are <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd> and <kbd>*</kbd> --
http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40

For the Tcl parser generally, yes there's a few more things you have to think about -- http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Answer (score 1):

Another (and simpler IMO) approach is to just search the string for the presence of the given substring and see if the search succeeded, like this:

```
set found [expr {[string first $needle $haystack] >= 0}]
```

This is just a plain search, none of the strings gets interpreted in any way so no worries about escaping.

In other words, your particular need is just too simple to throw tools intended for more heavier lifting at it. For instance, you'd want to use regex or glob matching if you'd need to search for, say, "a substring starting with `<FaultCode>` then containing a set of adjacent characters in the range '0'-'9' and ending with `</FaultCode>`"--that would be it, with regex engine, in particular, allowing you to extract that indeterminate substring of digit characters from the string.

Also I feel like I should make a note obligatory in cases like this: it's not wise to parse XML with anything but XML tools. In particular, there are [tclsoap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tclsoap) and [tdom](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tdom).

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't know TCL, just regular expressions*

[Apparently](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html), in TCL, it's recommended to surround your regex with double quotes `"regex"` or curly braces `{regex}` - then you don't need to worry about escaping anything that's not a regex reserved character.

I'm pretty sure that `<` and `>` don't need to be escaped.

I didn't know that `*` could be used as the surrounding items though - that's a reserved regex character.
Given this, I'd recommend doing this instead: `{<FaultCode>9000</FaultCode>}`

Comment: I was using the * as their intended purpose in regex, a wildcard. I believe with one at each end, it will return true if my string in between them is anywhere in the string, which is what I would like.

Comment: FYI, `string match` doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: Ah my bad - I was blinded by the "regex" tag. @Joshua, if you do want to use a wildcard in regex, it actually looks like `.*` since `*` applies to the item preceding it and should not be used by itself.

Comment: If string match doesn't use regex, what are the * for? I found this concept in an example.

Comment: Looks like it is a catch all operator: http://www.invece.org/tclwise/strings.html `*xyz*         can match xyz, fooxyz, fooxyzbar, and so on.`